# Trying to capture unidirectional tcp data on a server

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm trying to test linux behavior for unidirectional tcp capture using tcpdump.

The scenario is that Server A is sending packets to destination Y through a switch M.  At the same time, M will also be sending the same packets to destination Z, where I'd like to capture all packets.  The connection A to Y is a tcp connection.

In order to synthesize the above scenario, I have 3 terminals open on server Z running the following commands:

1. `nc -l 0.0.0.8 4444`
2. `telnet -b 0.0.0.10 0.0.0.8 4444`
3. `tcpdump -i <interface name associated with 0.0.0.8> port 4444`

0.0.0.8 and 0.0.0.10 are separate NIC cards in separate slots, slot 1 and slot 6 in this case.

From the telnet session, i'm successful in sending data, however, tcpdump isn't capturing any packets.  If I remove the `port 4444` from the terminal 3, I'm seeing data from within my network, but never anything from the `telnet` session.  I should also note that I'm not receiving an error message either.

I'm assuming, b/c I read it on the internet, that telnet creates a tcp connection, which is why I believe that tcpdump should work.  Am I wrong here?  Should I be doing something else?  Can't use WireShark or the like on this server.

Also, on terminal 3 I've also tried `tcpdump host 0.0.0.8 port 4444` to no avail.  Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: The OS might be bypassing the NICs because the source and destination are on the same machine, so tcpdump can't capture it. Unix.SE or SuperUser.com would be better places for this question, since it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

If node M is truly a switch and not a hub, then node Z should never receive the TCP packets destined for node Y.

TCP is a connection based protocol. That is to say that when node A wants to talk to node Y, it will first broadcast an ARP request asking for node Y's MAC address (note that all nodes attached to the switch will see this packet). When node Y responds directly to node A with it's MAC address, then node A will initiate a TCP connection directly to node Y.

If node M is a switch, it will only forward packets destined for MAC address F directly to the port which it knows to be attached to the node having MAC address F. It will never forward that packet to all ports, but only to the destination node's port.

On the other hand, if node M is a hub, it will always forward all packets to all ports regardless of destination.